# GeoTrace email Address

Tags: email, gmail, geolocation, security

Is is possible to geo lookup a Gmail sender ?  The gmail headers contain information about the routing of the email and the originating IP of the email. However, someone who sends you an email from GMail can ONLY be traced back to the GMail servers. So if Google load balance their datacenters geographically which means emails originating from EU would be in servers physically located in EU , so you can atleast say that the sender is somewhere in EU. Am I right on this ?

Comment: Do you want to know how to locate a person or what Blackberry's policy is?

Comment: both..if you read my question

Comment: It's because you're asking two different questions in the one post. You start on one track and then flip it on the tangent.

Comment: You're right..i've edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

> So if Google load balance their
>   datacenters geographically which means
>   emails originating from EU would be in
>   servers physically located in EU , so
>   you can atleast say that the sender is
>   somewhere in EU. Am I right on this ?

not if the the sender is using a proxy server. can be anywhere in the world.